# How execute an AutoIt script on remote machine

Tags: security, alert, remote-access, autoit

I need to run [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) tests on a remote machine. I use [JUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit), [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant), and [Jenkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29).

I run tests in Internet Explorer, and I need to handle a security window. I do this using [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt).

I find out how execute an AutoIt script remotely:

```
Robotil robotil=new Robotil("*ip*", 6666);  
robotil.invokeApplication("C:\\autoIT.exe");
```

It is executed when I am logged on the remote machine, but when I log out, it looks like the script doesn't execute and the security alert is not dismissed.

How do I solve this issue? Should I maybe set up some parameters on my remote machine?

It is interesting that using the same way, I could copy a file from a local to a remote machine, and then I am logged out:

```
Robotil robotil=new Robotil("*ip*", 6666);  
robotil.putFile("C:\\sourceFile.txt","C:\\destFile.txt");
```

Maybe there is another way to execute AutoIT script remotely?

AutoIt script:

```
Func GUIExit()
Exit
EndFunc
WinWaitActive ("Windows Security", "" ,1000000)
ControlClick ("Windows Security", "", "Cancel")
GUIExit()
```

Screenshot of alert:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was I have used standard windows remote desktop client. I install and run other and script works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try changing the code from this:

```
Func GUIExit()
Exit
EndFunc
WinWaitActive ("Windows Security", "" ,1000000)
ControlClick ("Windows Security", "", "Cancel")
GUIExit()
```

To this:

```
While 1
    If WinExists("Windows Security") Then
        WinActivate("Windows Security")
        WinWaitActive ("Windows Security", "", 30)
        IF WinActive("Windows Security") Then Send("{ESC}")
    EndIf
    Sleep(1000)
Wend
```

Can you remotely invoke notepad or something like that?  Are you sure that the path C:\autoit.exe exists on the remote machine?

Comment: The above code works, but still, only if I am connected to remote machine and watch the test is runnig. As soon as I minimize window with remote desktop - script is not executed. I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Take out the `Exit` line, and change the `1000000` to something a bit more reasonable like `30`.  Then, add `IF WinActive("Windows Security") Then` in front of the `Send("{ESC}")` in order to make sure we don't accidentally exit something else.  Then this program will just sit there and run constantly

Comment: I tried all this, autoit script is invoked, but don't click on that security window then it is minimized, maybe the problem is in some remote machine settings?